# Modelling with Code First-style in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, cardinality

I'm pretty new to Entity Framework and want to create a (personal) quick reference manual. The goal with it is to give myself some really short `code first` examples with different cardinalities:

- `one-to-one`
- `one-to-many`
- `many-to-many`

Here is what I have done so far:
[image]
First of all, I am very well aware that there are several threads on this particular subject out there (I've read a lot, many with confusing opposite statements).
Second, I'm only interested in `[Data Annotation]`-style (not in any kind of fluent APIs!).

Many sources out there confuses me, but just to make my question short: Is it really necessary to ever use the `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey]`-attribute (I mean in my `one-to-many` and `many-to-many` code examples)?

**Edit 1:** [Moho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1464084/moho) provided me with a [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) and I updated my model (one-to-one) according to what I understood from the information found [there](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx):
[image: One-to-One]

Should I have the same string in `[ForeignKey("<nav prop1>")]` as which I have in the name of my virtual property `public virtual Locker <nav prop2> { get; set; }`? I. e. is `<nav prop1> = <nav prop2>`?

Answer (score 1):

Your 1-1 example is not accurate - technically N `Locker`s can refer to a single `Student`, and N `Student`s can refer to a single `Locker`, but EF will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with message "Unable to determine the principal end of an association"

Use a shared primary key to enforce 1-1 relationship (attribute the PK field with both `[Key]` and `[ForeignKey("<nav prop>")]`

More reading on the topic [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)